# Filters, nets and Galois correspondence

Tags: general-topology, galois-theory, filters, nets

In the lecture, our prof. mentioned that the correspondence between nets and filters is a Galois correspondence without giving any more details about that.

In algebra, the proof of the Galois correspondence theorem we compared orders of the fixed field of H-automorphism and the order of the subgroup H and concluded that they must be equal due to the fact that the order is finite.

How can I think of a Galois correspondence of filters and nets? What are their groups, if there are any. If there are, what gives the finiteness in this correspondence?

Comment: Could it be the case that he meant the Galois connection, instead of the actual correspondence between fields and groups in Galois theory? (which is a special case of a Galois connection) (For a brief intro, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection; for a more detailed explanation, I'd recommend looking at some book about order theory (e.g. Ïntroduction to Lattices and Orders by Davey and Priestley).

Comment: Galois correspondence is a particular case of Galois connection. I suggest you to see the following link http://math.uga.edu/~pete/integral.pdf , Chapter 2 is dedicated to this argument.

Comment: thank you for that. I never heard of a Galois connection so far, but I am quite sure that this will solve my problem in understanding.

Comment: Have a look at chapter 7 of http://www.math.tamu.edu/~saichu/netsfilters.pdf. Note that there is an error in the first definition of that chapter. The condition of $\Psi$ being a subnet of $\Phi$ has $\Psi$ and $\Phi$ interchanged.

Comment: @Stefan: file does not exist.

Comment: @GEdgar: You can click on the link "see an archived version of this page" at the bottom.