# isomorphism filter and nets

Tags: general-topology, filters, nets

Given a filterbasis, by picking up an point out of every element of this filterbasis, and considering the ordering on the elements of the filterbasis  $u\leq v$ iff $v \subset u$ (subquestion why is it not the other way like subset v) , we get a net.

Given a net over I,  we get a filterbasis by considering $ \{ x_k| k \geq i \}$,for all $i \in I $.

Can we write a isomorphism between the set of all filters and the set of all nets. Or is there a filter not derivable from a net (or vice versa).

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359228/filters-nets-and-galois-correspondence) they claim there is a Galois connection, i cant see the pdf an am curious how that actually would be prooven, if there is no isomorphism.

Comment: The excellent PDF by Saitulaa Naranong can still be seen via the [WayBack Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130308175220/http://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Esaichu/netsfilters.pdf). Note that $\Psi$ and $\Phi$ have been inadvertently interchanged in the displayed line in **Definition** $\mathbf{10.2}$ at the top of page $11$. The one-sentence paragraph two lines down (‘In other words ...’) is correct.

Comment: And yes, there is a natural correspondence between the two; see **Lemma** $\mathbf{5.3}$. For your subquestion, think about convergence: it’s the tails of the net that have to get close to the limit point, and it’s the smaller nbhds that are close to that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More precisely, if $\mathcal{F}$ is a filterbase on $X$, then on the directed set

$$I(\mathcal{F}) = \{(x,F): x \in F \in \mathcal{F}\}; (x_1,F_1) \le (x_2, F_2) \iff F_2 \subseteq F_1$$

we have a net $\Phi(\mathcal{F}); I(\mathcal{F}) \to X; (x,F) \to x$. (so we consider *all* choices for points from $F$ simultaneously, so no AC is needed in the definition, it's all *canonical*).

And indeed we have an inverse by using tails:

If $f: I \to X$ is a net defined on some directed set $I$, we define

$$\mathcal{F} = \{ \{f(i): i \in I, i \le i_0\} \mid i_0 \in I\} $$

the tail filter $\Psi(f)$ defined by $f$. And indeed these maps are each other's inverse (see [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20130308175220/http://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Esaichu/netsfilters.pdf) (thx to Brian) for complete proofs).

This correspondence is "Galois" in the order reversal properties : a subnet of a net corresponds (under this map) to a larger filterbase, and vice versa, a larger filter(base) makes for a subnet.

Comment: What do you mean whit AC?

Comment: @user23657 the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) (wiki) e.g.